# Donation button/link in a free app

Tags: button, app-store, donations

Good day all,

I've recently developed an app that will be submitted soon to the App Store. I want to submit this app for free and was wondering if I could implement a button with the PayPal donation logo where it basically says "Donate for developing" or something related to that. I've seen many posts going around donations and apps. What I haven't found exactly is if I am allowed to have a donation button that will take the user to a PayPal link in Safari where they can make a donation for my development.

Am I allowed to do it?
Will Apple reject my app because of this?
Do you have any experience regarding this situation?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple will likely reject apps with a donate button taking you to PayPal.

You could implement in-app purchase to remove ads or something.  That takes you to Apple's App store, which Apple does allow.  And I am not sure whether an app actually needs to display ads in order to have an in-app purchase button to remove ads.

Or put a donate button on your web site, not on the app.

Comment: Thanks, I've decided to take the donation button out. Will monetize my app with ads. Cheers!

Comment: I've passed the review process twice with a PayPal donate button inside the app. However, after reading this comment, I'm not going to risk having my app pulled from the store some time in the future, when Apple does notice the button. The best solution is to link to your Web site, where a donate button can be placed.

Comment: I passed my application once with a donate button. But the following version got rejected.